# How to remove .php extension only for file after the first slash?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I am trying to remove the .php extension only from the file after the first slash.

Right now I have:

> example.com/file.php/123123

What I want is:

> example.com/file/123123

I have tried adding this code to the .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(e)/?$ /$1.php [L,NC]
```

It successfully removes the .php extension but only for the last part of the URL. 
Meaning it reads:

> example.com/file/123123

as:

> example.com/file/123123.php

and then makes it unable to load because there is no 123123.php.

How can I make it so it only tries to remove the .php from the after the first slash?
Thanks

Comment: Write a rule specific to `file/\d+` instead of using that overadvertised ".php removal" boilerplate.

Comment: What do you mean by writing a specific rule to file/\d+?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^file/(\d+)$ …`. See also: [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](//stackoverflow.com/q/20563772) for some quick intro. (mod_rewrite is not just magic .htaccess codez;)

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Remove php extension from htaccess but keep PATH\_INFO functional](//stackoverflow.com/q/37605999), [Remove .php extension with PHP](//stackoverflow.com/q/1337695), [Removing .php extension with mod\_rewrite and SEO issues](//stackoverflow.com/q/3697120), [Apache + PHP without ".php" File Extension but Including Path Info](//stackoverflow.com/q/26000528) etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `mod_rewrite` module installed and enabled, you can paste the following code into your `apache2.conf` file:

```
<Directory /path/to/site/folder>
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R,L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
        RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
        RewriteRule (.*) $1.html [L]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

This module can be installed by default, so you can just try with this code. It may work.